# Java FX привязка к переменной по Id

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Давно уже увлекаюсь java в свободное время и решил начать изучать javafx(Буквально часа два назад). И я некоторые моменты не понял. Есть fxml файл в котором описываться сцена, есть Controller который указан в этом fxml и он же обрабатывает всякие взаимодействие пользователя с интерфейсом, main.java запускает все это. Скажем у меня есть такой fxml:

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.151" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <children>
      <Button text="Faariz click" fx:id="btn_view"/>
 </children>
</GridPane>
```

И есть Controller.java:

```
public class Controller{
@FXML
private Button button;

@FXML
public void initialize(){
    button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            button.setText("Thanks!");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Так вот выводит ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:15)
```

Понятное дела но это код я взял из интернета. Так вот вопросы
1)Правильно ли я все понял?
2)есть ли какой нибудь метод типа findViewById как в андроид чтобы привязать view с переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя элемента `Button`, заданное через атрибут `fx:id`, должно соответствовать имени поля `Button` в контроллере.

```java
@FXML
private Button button;
```

```xml
<Button text="Faariz click" fx:id="button"/>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Имя переменной Button должен быть такой как id?

Comment: Ну да Ну да Ну да

Comment: Беляков понятно. Только почему я про это негде не увидел. Спасибо заработало

Comment: Маленький нюанс: только не в `id`, а в `fx:id`, т.к. `id` это привязка к файлу .css.

Answer (score 0):

До элемента можно добраться по аналогии с findViewById в Андроиде с помощью кода:

```java
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("../fmxl/main.fxml")); 
AnchorPane pane = loader.load(); 
Map<String, Object> fxmlNamespace = loader.getNamespace(); 
BorderPane border = (BorderPane) fxmlNamespace.get("border");
```

Где border это соответственно fx:id от BorderPane